# Go pointer dereferencing

Tags: go, pointers, dereference

I'm currently trying to learn GO and mainly knowing and working with Java, ASP.Net and some Python, there is no experience working with C-like pointers, which causes my current confusion.

A library I'm currently using to write my first GO project is called [Commando](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/thatisuday/commando#section-documentation).
There I have the struct [CommandRegistry](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/thatisuday/commando#CommandRegistry) and the variable of interest is called Commands.

In the struct the variable is described as the following:

```
// registered command configurations
Commands map[string]*Command
```

On a first glimpse I would understand this as a Map object containing a list of Strings, however it also shows the pointer reference to the actual Command object.

All I can see is that it is a map I can loop over which returns the name of the command ( the string ),
however I'm wondering if the `*Command` in the type description means I can somehow dereference the pointer and retrieve the object itself to extract the additional information of it.

As I know the `&` operand is used to create a new pointer of another object. `Pass-by-reference` basically instead of `pass-by-value`.
And the `*` operand generally signals the object is a pointer or used to require a pointer in a new function.

Is there a way I can retrieve the `Command` object or why does the type contain the `*Command` in it's declaration?

Comment: it's a map, so you can get the value for your string key `Commands["key"]` should give you the pointer to your Command. In Java this would be declared as `Map<String, Command>` - without pointers.

Comment: `Commands` is a map, it maps from string values to `*Command`, that is, pointer to `Command`. Indexing the map will give you the associated `*Command` pointer, e.g. `Command["foo"]`. You can dereference that (if it's not `nil`). You can also iterate over the map with a loop, getting all key-value pairs, like this: `for s, cmd := range Commands { fmt.Printf("key: %s, value: %v", s, cmd) }`

Comment: https://gobyexample.com/range

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick comments.
Indeed it seems I was blinded by the new topic of pointers and overlooked the simple solution that it still is a map just declared differently.

Comment: Note that you don't have to dereference the pointer in most cases, you can access the struct's fields and call it's methods using the pointer, it is basically short-hard for dereferencing so that you don't have to do it every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Commands` is a map (dictionary) which has strings as keys, and pointers to Commands as values. By passing it a key, you will get a pointer to the command it belongs to. You can then dereference the pointer to an actual `Command` object by using the `*` operator. Something like `dereferencedCommand := *Commands["key"]`.

The `*` operator can be quite confusing, at least it was for me. When used as a type it denotes that we are receiving the memory address of some variable. But to dereference a memory address to a concrete type, you also use the `*` operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and explanation of the * operator. It indees is a bit confusing when working with it for the first type.